# Change angle of arc (canvas)

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am Creating Semi Arc using Canvas my query here was I need to change the overall angle of the arc as per the expected image

Expected Image

[image]

Here is the HTML code for the Semi arc

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="250"></canvas>
```

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/bW4va/)

Thanks in advance
Maha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use the `bezierCurveTo` function. [Here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-bezier-curves/)'s a good resource for that, as you'll probably have to tweak the code to get your curve exactly how you want it.

Answer (score 1):

That curve can be approximated using `context.quadraticCurveTo`:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/f8fDj/

```
// x,y are the left,top point of the arc

function myCurve(x,y){    
    ctx.translate(x,y);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(85,18,150,0);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.translate(-x,-y);
}
```

Comment: hi @markE thanks for sharing the code but i don't want in image i want use canvas for that can you provide me solution

Comment: The `myCurve` function above draws the arc in the canvas.  I only drew the image so you could see the arc function correctly approximates that image: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2yN9Y/ ;=)

Comment: Hi @markE you mean to say i need to put myCurve function in my code and i need to call the function end of code

Comment: awesome @MarkE I got it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mark for the solution.

Here is the solution

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');    
 myCurve();

 function myCurve(x,y){    
  ctx.translate(x,y);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(85,18,150,0);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.translate(-x,-y);
```

}

Thanks & Regards
Maha